# how to fix class-accuracy of my classifier

Tags: python, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to see the accuracy of my image classifier for each class of my data. However, I am quite a beginner and I am trying to use the code provided by Pytorch tutorial on training a classifier.
When I run the code:

```
class_correct = list(0. for i in range(7))
class_total = list(0. for i in range(7))
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in test_loader:
        images, labels = data
        outputs = network(images)
        print(outputs.shape)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        c = (predicted == labels.argmax(dim=1)).squeeze()
        print(c.shape)
        for i in range(5):
            label = labels[i]
            class_correct[label] += c[i].item()
            class_total[label] += 1
for i in range(7):
    print('Accuracy of %5s : %2d %%' % (
        classes[i], 100 * class_correct[i] / class_total[i]))
```

"
The below error emerges:

```
torch.Size([100, 7])
torch.Size([100])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-b4cabf540645> in <module>
     11         for i in range(5):
     12             label = labels[i]
---> 13             class_correct[label] += c[i].item()
     14             class_total[label] += 1
     15 for i in range(7):

TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
```

I know the problem is with the label tensor but I don't know how to fix it.
Any help is highly appreciated!
Thank you all in advance

In the previous cell, I have run the code provided below to get the overall accuracy which worked but I have a problem getting the accuracy per class.

```
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in test_loader:
        images, labels = data
        outputs = network(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels.float().argmax(dim=1)).sum().item()

print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
    100 * correct / total))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code on my hand, so I'm just guessing.. but

I think the variable label is not a type of int.

```
#label = labels[i]
label = int(labels[i])
```

I hope it may help you

---

Sorry, actually I didn't pay enough attention for your question. I've read your code again.

I hope it may help you.

```
label_index = labels.argmax(dim=1)
for i in range(labels.size(0)):
    #label = labels[i]
    label = label_index[i]
    class_correct[label] += c[i].item()
    class_total[label] += 1
```

The key point : the variable labels is probability function or the one-hot encoded. You need to get the index of the maximum.

I really hope it works...!!

Comment: when I implemented your suggested change the below error emerged: ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars.
I guess the problem is with the dimension of my label tensor as when I run print(labels.shape) it says (100,7) I guess it should be a 1-dimensional tensor or something! Thanks again

Comment: I added another solution, please check it^^